# Logging Django SQL queries with DEBUG set to False

Tags: sql, django, optimization, django-orm

I know that it is possible to get all the SQL queries that were run for the current request/response when DEBUG is on by looking at [connection.queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running). The [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) also helps a lot on development.

The problem is that my production server is under high load and I would like to log the queries that are being executed for each view so I can optimize the pages that are creating more queries first.

Is it possible to do that without modifying my database driver?

Answer (score 5):

In Django 1.3, I see class `BaseDatabaseWrapper` in `django/db/backends/__init__.py` has an attribute `use_debug_cursor`. This class is the wrapper for the `django.db.connection` object that represents the default database connection ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)). Seems like setting this attribute to true would cause Django to use a `CursorDebugWrapper` from `django/db/backends/util.py`, which logs all queries it executes, instead of a `CursorWrapper`, which does not.

`use_debug_cursor` is not present in Django 1.2, which is what I have installed on this machine at the moment, so I can't test it right now. If I have a few minutes, I'll try to get a dummy 1.3 project started to test this out...I may well be in over my head here!

`use_debug_cursor` was renamed to `force_debug_cursor` in Django 1.8