# How do I print the queries executed by django .save() method?

Tags: sql, django

I want to see what queries are executed on django's model .save() method. Since I am in a production environment, I can't use Django Toolbar for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running
2. In Django 1.3 and above you can use logging which I believe dumps your sql queries into the log. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Doesn't seem like there's a straight-forward easy way without DEBUG=True. This is the closest I could find: [Logging Django SQL queries with DEBUG set to False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181511/logging-django-sql-queries-with-debug-set-to-false)

Comment: right, but the question asks specifically for .save() and DEBUG=True is not an option since I can't set my live server in DEBUG. I also can't reproduce my issue on my debug environment.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's a straight-forward easy way without DEBUG=True. This is the closest I could find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181511/logging-django-sql-queries-with-debug-set-to-false

Comment: Maybe you can set your database to [log queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) (beware: slows it up)

Answer (score 5):

Based on Sid's answer and this snippet (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1973/) i've replace the postgres db-wrapper with this:

```
# base.py
from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base import *

#http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1973/
class DatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapper):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.use_debug_cursor = True
```

Then in `settings.py`, use `'ENGINE': 'my_project.db_backend'`, instead of the default backend (in my case, `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`,)

Now `connection.queries` will contain all your queries!